# Stripe Payment error in multiple event registration when price amounts are different

Tags: payment-processor, stripe

I am finding an error in a **multiple event registration** when the fee amounts to pay are different for the different participants to the event. The Strip Payment Processor is raising the following error:

"***Stripe Payment Error**: This PaymentIntent's amount could not be updated because it has a status of requires capture. You may only update the amount of a PaymentIntent with one of the following statuses: requires_payment_method, requires_confirmation, requires_action*."

Is there anyone who can help me to fix this error?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There has been a draft to fix issue for Multiple event registration

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/24781